# How to Send "ESC+3" and "ESC+E" in Python telnetlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnet, keystroke, telnetlib

How to Send "ESC+3" and "ESC+E" in Python telnetlib.

Code:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
tn.write(ESC+3)
```

Now what I have to give in the place of ESC+3

Comment: In my experience, ESC is a normal character value 0x1B

Comment: @ZangMingJie So, Shall I give `tn.write("\x1B33")`

Comment: give it a try. BTW, it is `"\x1B3"`

Answer (score 0):

You can found the ASCII code from:

When found the code, write the data.

```
tn.write("\x1B\x33")
```